# Change cursor (pointer) image

Tags: html, css, cursor

I changed the image of the default cursor with:

```
html {
    cursor: url("media/custom.cur"),auto;
}
```

This is only for the default cursor.
How is it possible to change the pointer?

thx

Answer (score 1):

Try to define a cursor for all elements that would normally have a pointer cursor, and add `pointer` after the URL, like this:

```
a, button, input[type=submit], input[type=reset] {
    cursor: url("..."), pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`body{
     cursor:url('url of the image in single quotes') 2 2, auto;
}`

2 2 - is the x, y co-ordinate values, its your choice.

auto - keyword automatically determine the links and etc.